# Launch Screen storyboard showing up in simulator but not device when iPad Pro

Tags: ios, xcode

Not sure what I'm missing here, but the launch screen works fine on every device but iPad Pro. The launch screen is indeed a storyboard. It actually works perfectly fine on the iPad Pro simulator.

Any suggestions?

Update:

Ok, so I've added a tileable image to xcassets. There are three sizes. No matter how I slice it, it always shows up as expected in the storyboard and the simulator, but it never renders on device. Frustrating!

Comment: I have found that everything works fine on one iPad Pro and not another. Must be some kind of OS issue.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so nothing was really wrong on my end at all? Very strange issue. I installed the same binary on two different iPad Pros, both running the same version of iOS. On one, the launch screen was shown, and on the other it just displayed a black screen instead of the launch screen.

I know this isn't a technical "answer," but I want this in a prominent place so others don't go down the same path.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the binary from the device then reinstalling the app fixed this issue for us.